# Jenkins: plugin to set environment variable on parameter choice

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the [Active Choice](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) plugin. I can choose between param1 or param2.

This is fine. I can use param1 inside my job and it will do the stuff for param1 and vice versa. But now my job is expanding and I have to use multiple environment variables. Is there a plugin which is giving me the following choice:

```
IF choosing param1 THEN SET env variables env1=hello else env1=hi.
```

So I have to set environment variables which are dependent on the choice of my parameter in the beginning. I now I'm able to script it in shell or write a shell script for [the run condition plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) but I'd like to avoid this.

Is there a good plugin for this scenario in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The [Env Inject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin will allow you to do this.